# Create child of str (or int or float or tuple) that accepts kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, parent-child, subclass, keyword-argument

I need a class that behaves like a string but also takes additional `kwargs`. Therefor I subclass `str`:

```
class Child(str):

    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        # some code ...
        pass


inst = Child('a', y=2)
print(inst)
```

This however raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/Project/exp1.py", line 8, in <module>
    inst = Child('a', y=2)
TypeError: 'y' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Which is rather strange, since the code below works without any error:

```
class Child(object):

    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        # some code ...
        pass


inst = Child('a', y=2)
```

---

**Questions:**

- Why do I get different behavior when trying to subclass `str`, `int`, `float`, `tuple` etc compared to other classes like `object`, `list`, `dict` etc?
- How can I create a class that behaves like a string but has
  additional kwargs?

Comment: maybe something about the `__str__` or `__unicode__` methods that needs to be overridden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override `__new__` in this case, not `__init__`:

```
>>> class Child(str):
...    def __new__(cls, s, **kwargs):
...       inst = str.__new__(cls, s)
...       inst.__dict__.update(kwargs)
...       return inst
...
>>> c = Child("foo")
>>> c.upper()
'FOO'
>>> c = Child("foo", y="banana")
>>> c.upper()
'FOO'
>>> c.y
'banana'
>>>
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) for the answer to why overriding `__init__` doesn't work when subclassing immutable types like `str`, `int`, and `float`:

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types **(like int, str, or tuple)** to customize instance creation. It is also
>   commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class
>   creation.